# Why node/*/track appears as Referrer to node/*?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have the Statistics core module turned on in my Drupal 7 site.

When I visit the 'Track' tab of a node (node/X/track), the table shows that same page – node/X/track – listed several times as the 'Referrer' to the page itself – node/X. These visits are made by 'Anonymous (not verified)' users.

How can that happen if only the admin (myself) has the permission to view the 'Track' tab??

However, if I click on 'Details' for one of these anonymous visits (/admin/reports/access/*), the "Referrer' information is blank.

Is there some misconfiguration in my site or I did not understand how the Statistics module works?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the [`_statistics_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!statistics!statistics.module/function/_statistics_link/7) function and no referral data; this function relies on [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) and when an empty path (i.e. the referrer) is passed to it, it returns the current path which is `node/%node/track`.

So in other words, those are not anonymous users viewing the tracking page, rather it's anonymous users browsing directly to the page (or not sending referrer data).